# How to create a trigger on remote SQL Server 2005/2008 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I want to create a trigger on a table that exists on a remote SQL Server 2005/2008 database. I only have read only access to that database. My first question is, is this even possible?

If this is not possible what are my other options, because i want to listen to any changes on that table and perform some calculations.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have read-only access to the database, then no, you can't create triggers.

If all you have is read-only access to the remote database, the only possible ways I can think of doing it are;

- [Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) (ouch)
- Asking the DBAs to help you with the trigger creation or some kind of one-way replication.
  They may not be entirely unwilling to do so if the alternative is polling.

Comment: thanks for such a quick response. There is also Query Notifications can this be of some help? Will this work with read only rights?

Comment: @zahid Query notifications require the `SQL Server Notification Service` to be installed, and the user to have appropriate permissions (which I don't know from the top of my head, sorry). It's not installed by default, ad if you have read permissions only, it's unlikely to work.

Comment: @zahid Yes, read only access usually implies that you can't create any jobs/triggers/functions on the database side that will help you :-/ Without the help of a DBA at the remote site, I can't think of any other way. One idea to make it slightly more elegant is to make a separate process that polls the database and pushes changes to your regular application, that way you can change to notifications or triggers later without affecting your main app, and it gets a nicer interface to work against.